Firebase Genkit: how to set system / user /assistant chat history?
I am trying to use Firebase Genkit.
I see here that I can use:
import { generate } from '@genkit-ai/ai';

generate({
  model: 'googleai/gemini-1.5-flash-latest',
  prompt: 'You are a helpful AI assistant named Walt. Say hello.',
});

Great, it works.
Now, I want to use a chat history.
As mentioned here, I use:
const result = await multiTurnPrompt.generate({
  model: llama3x70b, 
  history: [
    { role: 'user', content: [{ text: 'Hello.' }] },
    { role: 'model', content: [{ text: 'Hi there!' }] },
  ],
});

Here is my code:
import {dotprompt, promptRef } from "@genkit-ai/dotprompt";
....
const multiTurnPrompt = dotprompt();

const result = await multiTurnPrompt.generate({
  model: llama3x70b, 
  history: [
    { role: 'user', content: [{ text: 'Hello.' }] },
    { role: 'model', content: [{ text: 'Hi there!' }] },
  ],
});

console.log(await result.text());

I get error:
TypeError: multiTurnPrompt.generate is not a function

How to solve this issue ?
UPDATE
Modified code following @Michael Doyle answer:
const multiTurnPrompt = promptRef('nameOfPrompt');

const result = await multiTurnPrompt.generate({

 model: llama3x70b, 

 history: [
    { role: 'user', content: [{ text: 'Hello.' }] },
    { role: 'model', content: [{ text: 'Hi there!' }] },
  ],

});

I get the error:
"GenkitError: dotprompt: NOT_FOUND: Could not find 'nameOfPrompt.prompt' in the prompts folder." 

I don't want to use a chat described in a chat file, I want to define the chat in my JS code as mentioned in the doc. How to do that ? Thanks.

Generally speaking, you are getting errors, because you are mixing and matching calls to generate(...), which let's you prompt models in an adhoc way, and dotprompt, which has prompt management features, as well as a shortcut to "run" a prompt (i.e. prompt.generate(...).
If you want to use chat history, we can stick to generate and modify your original code as follows:
import { generate } from '@genkit-ai/ai';

generate({
  model: 'googleai/gemini-1.5-flash-latest',
  prompt: 'You are a helpful AI assistant named Walt. Say hello.',
  history: [
    { role: 'user', content: [{ text: 'Hello.' }] },
    { role: 'model', content: [{ text: 'Hi there!' }] },
  ],
});

You can save the results from generate(...) to a variable, and call toHistory() on it, and then pass that history in to the next request. For example:
import { generate } from '@genkit-ai/ai';
import { gemini15Flash } from '@genkit-ai/googleai';

let response = await generate({
  model: gemini15Flash,
  prompt: "How do you say 'dog' in French?",
});
let history = response.toHistory();

response = await generate({
  model: gemini15Flash,
  prompt: 'How about in Spanish?',
  history,
});
history = response.toHistory();

The Genkit docs describe in more detail: https://firebase.google.com/docs/genkit/models#recording_message_history

Thanks for your answer. So I used: const multiTurnPrompt = promptRef('nameOfPrompt');
const result = await multiTurnPrompt.generate({
model: llama3x70b,
history: [
{ role: 'user', content: [{ text: 'Hello.' }] },
{ role: 'model', content: [{ text: 'Hi there!' }] },
],
}); but I get "GenkitError: dotprompt: NOT_FOUND: Could not find 'nameOfPrompt.prompt' in the prompts folder." I don't want to use a chat described in a chat file, I want to define the chat in my JS code as mentioned in the doc. How to do that ? Thanks. (I updated my question for code clarity)

Happy to help. Can you clarify a couple things?

Are you trying to build an interactive chat?
Will you have an initial starting prompt and/or system prompt?


@Michaael Doyle Sorry for my late answer. Yes, I am trying to build an interactive chat. I have a initial system and assistant/user history. Thanks for your help!
